# Simple way to compute shortest paths on a polyhedron

Tags: c#, geometry, wolfram-mathematica, computational-geometry, shortest-path

I am working on a little computational geometry library that uses Mathematica's NETLink to allow polytopes to be modeled in C# and controlled viewed via Mathematica. I hope to allow easy and exact manipulation of geometry, with a focus on geometry unfolding problems.

Currently I am looking to implement an exact shortest path's algorithm on a convex polyhedron. It's been suggested to me that I use [Chen and Han's](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=98601) algorithm to do this, and specifically that I look at [O'Rourke's implementation](http://www.cs.smith.edu/~orourke/papers.php#28). However, this is a pretty big task. Given that I'm starting with quick-and-dirty techniques for the rest of the functions, I'm looking for something simpler, even if it has significantly worse performance.

There is an algorithm by Sharir and Schorr that gets the shortest path in O(n^3) time (with n I assume being the number of vertices), but I can't seem to find the paper anywhere. I'm wondering if this algorithm is indeed simpler, if any implementations of it already exists, and just if anyone has some general advice.

Comment: Maybe these 2 videos will help(Dijkstra’s Algorithm) 1)http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJ5Ozb2ZSxM , 2) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87_1K2GQFdU , and this is a pdf on the lecture notes about the same topic http://www.cse.ust.hk/faculty/golin/COMP271Sp03/Notes/MyL09.pdf

Comment: Is [*On Shortest Paths in Polyhedral Spaces*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0215014) the paper by Sharir and Schorr you were looking for? First hit on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=Sharir%20Schorr%20polyhedron%20path). But they seem to be mostly talking about polyhedral *obstacles* and shortest paths *around* these.